# POSIX REGEX - Find all lines that contain "ONLY" a string in a specific format, but not a similar strings with additional parameters

Tags: mysql, regex

Trying to do some scripting for network automation. Our system is HP Network Automation, which uses a MySQL backend. Basically what I'm trying to do, is create a script that will find all the devices with a configuration that does not conform to a certain standard.

So, the strings we're examining:

```
snmp-server community blah RO
snmp-server community blah2 RW 1
snmp-server community blah3 RO blahacl
```

We want to find all similar lines, but only those without anything behind RO|RW.

So we want: `snmp-server community blah RO`
We do not want: `snmp-server community blah2 RW 1` or `snmp-server community blah3 RO blahacl`

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried a number of combinations, like `snmp-server.*?(RO|RW)( ?!\w|\W)` for instance, but it finds up to RO|RW for each of the lines. I don't want the ones that have characters after RO or RW...

Comment: POSIX regex with lookaheads and lazy matching?

Comment: What is the language? What is the regex library?

Comment: The Reference Guide states:
"Note: The contains (regexp) and does not contain (regexp) operators are based on the database-specific regular expression SQL queries. For detailed information, see the specific database SQL references— such as for Oracle database, see the  Oracle® Database SQL Reference ."

In this case we're using MySQL (Not Oracle)

Comment: You should have mentioned that at the start. Try `WHERE col REGEXP BINARY '^snmp-server.* R[OW]$'`, or `WHERE col REGEXP BINARY '^snmp-server.*[[:<:]]R[OW]$'`

Answer (score 1):

Since it is MySQL, you just cannot use lazy dot matching and negative lookaheads.

Also, a word boundary pattern is very specific in MySQL, it is `[[:<:]]` (for a leading word boundary) and `[[:>:]]` (a trailing one). So, if you need to match entries starting with `^snmp-server` and ending with a whole word `RO` or `RW`, use

```
WHERE col REGEXP '^snmp-server.*[[:<:]]R[OW]$'
```

To match in a case sensitive way, add `BINARY` keyword:

```
WHERE col REGEXP BINARY '^snmp-server.*[[:<:]]R[OW]$'
```

Since this expression is generic due to `.*`, you might want to restict it by replacing the `.*` with the amount of non-whitespace chunks and known literals.
If `snmp-server` and `community` are there at the beginning and then a non-whitespace chunk should come right after and `RO` to follow, you can use

```
WHERE col REGEXP BINARY '^snmp-server community [^[:space:]]+ R[OW]$'
```

This will match entries strictly like `snmp-server community some123$%^-thing_here RO` or `snmp-server community some&*|2-thing_there RW`.

Comment: Hmmm.... doesn't like `[[:<:]]` - gives _Invalid Criteria String: Element type "value" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"_  I assume something to do with the code in the background that's passing the string... 

Other funny thing is it seems like it should work with `$`, but it almost seems like it's completely ignoring `^` or `$`. I may have to go to the vendor on this one as it seems to be a problem with how they're interpreting it.... unless you have any other ideas or alternative ways of doing it?

Comment: That is how it is done in MySQL, perhaps, you have yet something different.

Answer (score 0):

Try `snmp-server.*?(RO|RW)$`. `$` is end-of-line indicator for regex

Comment: as far as I know, there's no lazy quantifers in POSIX ERE.

Comment: Works perfectly for me...FYI - https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions

Comment: Many thanks. Had tried a few combinations with "$" to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following RegEx:

```
snmp-server.*?(RO|RW)$
```

`$` deliminates the end of a string, so this is stating that the string *must end with* `RO` or `RW`. This means that there can be no data after it

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/eY2sU2/1)</kbd>

Comment: Many thanks. Had tried a few combinations with "$" to no avail.

Comment: @BenShellrude Did you actually try this one?

Answer (score 0):

```
^snmp-server.*(blah\b) (RO|RW)$
```

- '$' matches end of string (a match ends at RO or RW)
- '\b' ensures there is a word boundary (end of word) after string 'blah', so if any characters are after blah, it will not match.
- make sure to enable multiline mode appropriate to whatever regex parser this is running in.

Just tested with the sample strings given and the POSIX option [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/golang/index.html), if I understand correctly it matches the first line in your sample text, but not the second or third.

Comment: This one seemed to hold promise for me (though "blah" could be any string containing any type of character - with exception of a space). Unfortunately it still didn't work. As I mentioned above, the reference guide for the HP product states that for this particular query/operator, the regex is based on database-specific REGEX SQL queries... So not sure if that has something to do with why it's not working...